# Lost a bunch of code in Github, mistakingly reverted to an old push, what are my options?

Tags: github

The commit no longer shows up but rather the latest one now is the one named "Instructions work".

https://images.discordapp.net/.eJwFwQEOwiAMAMC_8ABahqNlv2mYcUYpy9plica_e_cN5_EOS9jcd1sA1qe1cazRcpQun6FyWWyjg7hL2_pd3aAWKnijMuGMzFQYEiYkToyUa5pznRBOfem4NO76CL8_2w8gBg.u1qWiqmlxQgWvh_ROTa4VHx2gCY.png?format=webp

That's the screenshot of my commit. I had a merge error and googled how to resolve it and did it. Didn't notice my commit disappeared. Pressed sync thinking i was pushing my commit. Actually reverted and my commits are gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git revert`shouldn't do anything except create a new commit -- you should be able to undo the revert by reverting to head with `git revert HEAD`

**EDIT:** 
You can also search for dangling commit blobs in your lost and found history using `git fsck --lost-found` and then find the one you want and then apply the commit with `git merge <SHA1 of commit>`.

Comment: Perhaps reverted is the wrong word. It's just disappeared. here's my git history now. http://i.imgur.com/9kB8GNR.png

Comment: what "should" the history look like to you?

Comment: I should see a bunch of my commits. my user is sczin. In the first image I have a bunch of commits since 4 days ago. Now i dont. This is what happens when your team doesn't help you decide to try and push anyway.

Comment: try to check for your dangling commits with `git fsck --lost-found`

Comment: if you find dangling commits (the SHA1) with the `git fsck --lost-found` command that you want to immediately apply you can do a `git merge <SHA1 of commit>`

Comment: Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (198/198), done.
dangling blob 3961b31e37e8010416133e34b4734916eb9f84b3
dangling blob 40a29f2f9593bf3f8c960362c621be48cc9bc7a1
dangling blob 6482c7180b9323836e404fa711d9bdf8e2fa3a83
dangling blob fc03e4d8e08808a7750665669783634f62bd53fe
dangling commit 2ca5c39278ae5f0c31d2de49e850e5eeae82d8ca
dangling blob ea95e1b928770d12181267ca34ad74b131a7383c

etc what do i do?

Comment: So, you need to find out (or guess) which one of the danglings blobs are the commit you want (assuming they are in that group of blobs) and then do a `git merge` on it, for example it you want the commit blob `40a29f2f9593bf3f8c960362c621be48cc9bc7a1`, you want to do `git merge 40a29f2`

Answer (score 0):

You can try reverting the actual revert commit.

Comment: I'm getting "unable to revert commit". The problem is that I synced it and it changed all my files which were apparently only local despite my commits in the screenshot.

Comment: I do not see recent commits in history.
If you rebased without committing your wanted changes, then you are probably out of luck.